# Field level permissions django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know what are the best ways we can assign field level permissions in Django given the user . If the role of the user is employeee. In the same form used for all the roles . I want some fields to be read only . Is there any way that could happen and how .
I tried using this in forms didn't work though .

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  user = kwargs.pop('user')
  super(ProgramForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                 
  if user.role =='ver': ProgramForm.fields['balise_id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Comment: use `self.fields['balise_id']`, not `ProgramForm`, you are dealing with instance of the form

Comment: Thanks for that . Is there any other way to do it as well ?